# bazel cross compile tensorflow with opencl support

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencl, cross-compiling, bazel

I am able to build tensorflow for arm platform using cross toolchain as described in

[bazel cross compile](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/test/shell/bazel/testdata/bazel_toolchain_test_data)

But Tensorflow supports building with OpenCL support when we run './configure' from tensorflow home Directory where we get below questions

> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N]: y
>   OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>   Please specify which C++ compiler should be used as the host C++
>   compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/g++]: 
>  Please specify which C compiler
>   should be used as the host C compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 
>   Please specify the location where ComputeCpp for SYCL 1.2 is
>   installed. [Default is /usr/local/computecpp]:

I would like to know how to enable opencl when building tensorflow for cross toolchain. I suspect the above configurations would get overridden by the configurations specified in cross toolchain

**Actual Requirement :** To cross-build Tensorflow using --config=sycl for arm 32 bit system

**Things Done**

1. Able to cross-build Tensorflow without --config=sycl for arm 32 bit system using below command

> bazel build --crosstool_top=//armv7l-compiler:toolchain
>   --cpu=armeabi-v7a tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so --cxxopt="-std=c++11"

**Result :** Built Fine without errors

2 cross-build Tensorflow without --config=sycl for arm 32 bit system using below command

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon" --crosstool_top=//armv7l-compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so --cxxopt="-std=c++11" --config=sycl
```

**Result**
Build Failed at Last moment while trying to link libComputeCpp.so

I have downloaded the sdk from codeplaysoftware website for Linux16.04 and arm64 bit. Can I know if there is 32 bit version

I basically wanted to improve the speed of TensorFlow on embedded 32 bit arm device by using opencl or sycl. Could you also please suggest any other optimization flags to be used while building.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think Bazel would not enable OpenCL for the target platform?

Comment: Because ComputeCpp/SYCL is currently supported for Desktop and arm64 version, but I am building for arm32 version, hence getting an error at lat moment of build saying - "failed to link libComputeCpp.so" which I have downloaded from codeplay website for arm64 bit. Futher details related to the issue https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/issues/68#issuecomment-348952794

Comment: I have two questions: (1) As I understand it, you can build without `--config=sycl`, but cannot build *with* the flag, correct? (2) Also, do I understand correctly that you downloaded a prebuilt arm64 object file and tried linking it with an arm32 linker? If so, that sounds wrong to me, I believe you'll need either a prebuilt arm32 object file, or build one yourself using Bazel or some other build tool. Also, you may need a different `--crosstool_top`; I don't know if the one you use supports arm32.

Comment: 1. Yes , I can build without --config=sycl and cannot build with --config=sycl, both using cross compilation for arm 32 bit       2. I do not find source code for building libComputecpp.so ( to cross build for arm32)

Comment: Could you please build with `--verbose_failures` and update the question with the output? In case anyone can answer, they'll find the log helpful. That said, I don't think you can link an arm64 object file with an arm32 linker. Maybe the ComputeCpp/SYCL people could say more about this, whether they can provide an arm32 object file.

Comment: I have found in that codeplay website, they are providing for arm32 also. Have you found successful results on building tensorflow with opencl support for arm? I am also trying the same but I am getting a different error than you mentioned. Can you kindly point me to the tensorflow version you are trying and your progress for arm